# File Upload control unable to browse

Tags: asp.net

i am using  fileupload control on my master page enable asp.net form . When i try to browse it should pop up a dialog box to show files but it does not work . i tried to debug it on console using chrome when i hit browse button it shows me this error . 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined** 
here is my html code

```
 <div id = "browse" margin-left:auto; margin-right:"100px";>
 <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />

</div>
```

Comment: This error has no relation to the download file. This mean that your jquery is not load correctly.

Comment: yes indeed i tried to uplaod new CDN but still having same issue

Comment: i am using this CDN <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: May be you load script too late.

Comment: @igor Semin i Loading CDN <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Comment: Try this valid url <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>. And no more. But i don't understand your problem - you can't insert jquery  to your page or can't upload file?

Comment: well i cant upload the file because when i click on upload button it throws this Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error instead of browsing file

Comment: Try moving script reference from asp:Content element to 'head' section of your masterpage.

Comment: well problem is resolved i downloaded new JQUERY and added this reference to my master page and it worked .<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my jQuery reference was too old in my solution. I did following steps and it worked:

1. downloaded latest jQuery library and removed previous one
2. Added new reference tag it worked perfectly:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   ```